# Orthogonal mapping $f$ which preserves angle between $x$ and $f(x)$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Let $f: \mathbf{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbf{R}^n$ be a linear orthogonal mapping such that 
$\displaystyle\frac{\langle f(x), x\rangle}{\|fx\| \|x\|}=\cos \phi$, where $\phi \in [0, 2 \pi)$.
Are there such mapping besides $id$, $-id$ in case whe $n$ is odd?
Is it true that if $n=2k$ then then there exists an orthogonal basis $e_1,\ldots,e_{2k}$ in $\mathbf{R}^{2k}$
such that the matrix $F$ of $f$ in that basis is of the form
$$
F=\left [ \begin{array}{rrrrrrrr}
A_1 & & &\\
 & A_2 & &\\
 & & \ddots \\
  & &  & A_{k}\\
 \end{array} \right  ],
$$
where
$$
A_1=A_2=\cdots=A_{k}=\left [ \begin{array}{rr}
\cos \phi & -\sin \phi \\
\sin \phi & \cos \phi \\
\end{array} \right  ] ?
$$

Thanks.

Comment: $F$ as you've given it is a $4k \times 4k$ matrix.  I think just leaving out the $B_i$ blocks should fix it, though.

Comment: Yes, you have right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly, if $\cos\phi=\pm1$, we must have $F=\pm id$. Thus we may consider only the case $\cos\phi\not=\pm1$.

A real *[normal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix)* matrix $A$ can be orthogonally block-diagonalized. More specifically, there exists orthogonal matrix $Q$ such that $QAQ^T = (|\lambda_1|R(\theta_1)) \oplus\ldots\oplus(|\lambda_k|R(\theta_k))\oplus \Lambda$, where each $\lambda_i$ is some (perhaps complex) eigenvalue of $A$, $R(\theta)$ means the $2\times 2$ rotation matrix by angle $\theta$, and $\Lambda$ is a real diagonal matrix. See, for instance, Theorem 2.5.8 (p.105) of Horn and Johnson's [Matrix Analysis](http://books.google.com/books?id=PlYQN0ypTwEC&pg=PA100&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Now, if $A$ is orthogonal, we must have $|\lambda_1|=\ldots=|\lambda_k|=1$ and all diagonal entries of $\Lambda$ must be $\pm1$. In other words, for some real orthogonal matrix $Q$, we have $F = QAQ^T = R(\theta_1)\oplus\ldots\oplus R(\theta_k)\oplus I_p\oplus (-I_q)$ for some $k,p,q$. Now, if $\langle Fx, x\rangle = \|Fx\| \|x\|\cos \phi$ for all $x$, similar equalities must also hold blockwise. Therefore, the two blocks $I_p$ and $-I_q$ must be void and $\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_k=\pm\phi$. So your assertion is correct. However, note that $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}R(-\phi)\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}^T = R(\phi)$. Therefore, we can actually choose an orthonormal basis such the matrix representation of $f$ is $R(\phi)\oplus\ldots\oplus R(\phi)$.

Answer (score 1):

Your orthogonal transformation $f$ can be "complexified" to a unitary transformation $U$ on ${\mathbb C}^n$ such that $U(x + i y) = f(x) + i f(y)$ for $x, y \in {\mathbb R}^n$.  Being normal, $U$ can be diagonalized, and its eigenvalues have absolute value 1.

The only possible real eigenvalues are $\pm 1$, in which case the eigenvectors can be chosen to be real as well; this corresponds to $\cos \phi = \pm 1$, and your cases $id$ and $-id$.

If $v = x + i y$ is an eigenvector for a non-real eigenvalue $\lambda = a + b i$, then $\overline{v} = x - i y$ is an eigenvector for $\overline{\lambda} = a - b i$.  Thus the eigenspaces for complex 
eigenvalues pair up.
Now $Uv = \lambda v = (a x - b y) + i (a y + b x)$, so $f(x) = a x - b y$ and $f(y) = a y + b x$.  Then 
$x^T f(x) = a \|x\|^2 - b x^T y = (\cos \phi) \|x\|^2$ and 
$y^T f(y) = a \|y\|^2 + b x^T y = (\cos \phi) \|y\|^2$. Therefore
$b x^T y = (a - \cos \phi) \|x\|^2 = -(a - \cos \phi) \|y\|^2$.  Since $b \ne 0$, $\|x\|>0$ and $\|y\|>0$, we must have $x^T y = 0$ and $a = \cos \phi$.  Since $|\lambda\|=\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} = 1$, $b = \pm \sin \phi$.  This gives you your $2 \times 2$ block $\pmatrix{\cos \phi & -\sin \phi \cr \sin \phi & \cos \phi\cr}$ or 
$\pmatrix{\cos \phi & \sin \phi \cr -\sin \phi & \cos \phi\cr}$ (but you don't need both of them).

Comment: Thanks for your beautiful answer.